# Is it possible to overwrite scripts? (OTA Update)

Tags: remote, update, pi-pico, micropython

I'm having a hard time finding information about remote updates on PICO W. I watched a bunch of videos demonstrating how MicroPython can be used to manipulate the flash storage - so would it be possible to fetch, say, `main.py` from a server and overwrite the existing file, then reboot?

Obviously, this will be handled by an updater of some sort, that also resides on the pico.

Answer (score 0):

It works in the Arduino IDE. Installing support for the PICO W there, it also give you some example sketches to get OTA up and running. First you have to give the PICO W some flash memory for the upload, so in Tools->Flash size, I set it to 512 kB. Then download the code to the PICO W via USB, it then turns up as a new wireless port which works as a OTA update. I havn't found any micro python code though.
https://arduino-pico.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ota.html
//Stefan